# How to do retopology?

Tags: modeling

So this seems to be an essential skill in blender when you sculpted something and it has to many vertices. I have tried to figure it out but all my attempts have either taken days to do some or ended in it still having way to many points. I have tried watching videos but the people doing just start doing it without without explaining anything and I can't seem to copy them just by visuals only I'm also heavily auditory.
So can you guys give me a few some tips or point me somewhere that can help me?
And please don't just type retopology into google or Youtube and post the first video that comes up. I tried that many times, so please make sure they are good first or you have used them before.

Comment: There are plenty videos explaining that. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+retopology
What you say is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't say enough about what your object looks like. Also, retopology is not the same as simplifying a mesh with deleting edge loops etc. But if you're talking about retopology, here is the basic way to begin in my opinion:

- Create a plane over the high-poly object you are supposed to retopologize. This plane will be your low-poly version.

[image]

- If your high-poly is symmetrical, give your low-poly a *Mirror* modifier. Enable the *Clipping* option.

[image]

- On the horizontal menu bar, disable the *Limit Selection to Visible* option, enable the *Snap*, choose the *Face* mode, enable all the snap options.

[image]

- Begin to move the vertices of your plane, you'll see that they will stick to the high-poly surface. Extrude edges, try to follow the main shapes and angles of the high-poly. About good topology and topology tricks, you can find some good advices [here](https://topologyguides.com/), it would take too long to summarize everything here.

[image]

Comment: That's the process I already use and got nothing but time consuming garbage.

Comment: what's the problem with this process? You don't have any easy way to do it, you can sometimes easily simplify a mesh if its topology makes it possible, that's all. But when you say "people doing just start doing it without without explaining anything", could you please be more specific? Because it's much too vague to help...

Answer (score 0):

There's a modifier for this. It's called [Decimate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html?). You'll might have to use either Collapse mode or  Planar mode because Un-Subdivide only works on quads. Let me know if this still doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Decimate often works fine for meshes that do not deform, but if you are modeling something like a human face, you need the edge loops to work well with the underlying muscle. I know it sucks to read this, but only experience will make you get this right, and you can always improve. Eventually you will get a "feel" for how the topology needs to be based on how a unique model will deform.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best way to make retopology with Blender is [RetopoFlow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow), an awesome addon capable of turn such a boring task into something that's almost fun.

You can buy the addon on Blendermarket and support the developers or download it for free on [GitHub](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow).

By the way, it's not a big deal but currently there isn't a 2.80 compatible version so you have to go with Blender 2.79 if you choose to retopo with RetopoFlow.

Comment: No problem that's exactly what I use, 2.8 has to many glitches